# How to UV map this image onto chrome material

Tags: materials, uv, node-editor, eevee-render-engine, uv-image-editor

I have already a chrome material applied to my object. And then I make the same material for the front of the object, and I want to UV this PNG image, but I don't know how to set up the NODE for it to display with the chrome material, I'm getting a black texture displayed, instead of the chrome material.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the alpha channel of your image as mask in order to put the smiley over the chrome material: Plug your *Image Texture* into a *Principled BSDF*, mix this *Principled* with the one with your chrome material into a *Mix Shader*, use the *Alpha* of the *Image Texture* as the factor of the *Mix Shader*. The settings of your first *Principled BSDF* can be different from the second, for example if you want something non-reflective for your smiley, etc:

[image]